# Format a date to a specific format in java?

Tags: java, date, date-format

I have a date in the format `11-NOV-13`
When i convert the date i get the value `Sat Nov 11 00:00:00 IST 13`.
But i want the converted date to be in the format `Sat Nov 11 00:00:00 IST 2013`.
Though i have used the `dateformat` it is not taking it. Can anyone point me where i am wrong?

Below is the code i have been working on

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date myDate = format.parse("11-NOV-13");
```

Comment: Search Stack Overflow before posting. This has been addressed many hundreds of times, if not thousands.

Answer (score 2):

Change the format to:

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are not providing the full year you need

```
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy", Locale.ENGLISH);
    Date myDate = format.parse("11-NOV-13");

    System.out.println(myDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the year 2 numbers:

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

You can reference the docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Answer (score 0):

Change to this format:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date myDate = format.parse("11-NOV-13");

String formattedDate = sdf.format(myDate);
```